# SELECT rows from a table joining only one row of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I Have two tables: Home(ID, name) and Photos(ID, homeid, filename, splash)

Home primary key is ID, Photos primary key is ID. A Home can have multiple photos. Splash can be 0 or 1 and, for each HomeID, at most one photo can have splash=1.

Now i'd like to SELECT * FROM Home merging for each home its splash, if exists, else splash returns null.

How can i do?

Here's an example of the tables:

```
Home
ID     name
1      home1
2      home3252
3      home5326

Photos
ID     homeid       filename       splash
1      1            asda.jpg       0
2      1            aspg.jpg       1
3      2            nasf.jpg       0
4      2            qfqj.jpg       1
5      3            vnas.jpg       0
6      3            nfao.jpg       0
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select h.name, p.filename
from Home h
left join Photos p on (h.id = p.homeid and p.splash = 1)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Problem solved. I was near to the solution but i was inserting in the "on" declaration only one equation. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question, use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` MySQL syntax...

Comment: thank you. i was using left outer join but i was declaring in the "on" declaration only (home.id = photo.homeid) and i was forgetting photo.splash = 1.